# Can Python add the " character to a string

Tags: python-2.7, formatting

I have to paste 3000 url's a day that are unformatted

Can i set up code to convert the raw paste data to a string?

(Example raw data) - 13 Michael Way Cottees NSW 2017

(Example changed data) - "13 Michael Way Cottees NSW 2017"

I have tried

```
RAW_URL = 13 Michael Way Cottees NSW 2017 + " "
RAW_URL = str(13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607)
RAW_DATA = ' " ' + (13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607) + ' " '
```

I keep getting "invalid syntax" error and not having much luck with google.

Once it's done it will be folded into the below code, to replace the single input on PASTED_CRM_DATA to a list just below

```
import requests
import csv
from lxml import html
import time
import sys

text2search = '''RECENTLY SOLD'''


PASTED_CRM_DATA = "13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607"
URL_LIST = 'https://www.realestate.com.au/property/' + str(PASTED_CRM_DATA.replace(' ', '-').lower()),


with open('REA.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
        page = requests.get(url)
        print '\r' 'Scraping URL ' + str(index+1) +   ' of  ' + str(len(URL_LIST))+ ' '  +  url,


        if text2search in page.text:
            tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

            (title,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
            (price,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//div[@class="property-value__price"]'))
            (sold,) = (x.text_content().strip() for x in tree.xpath('//p[@class="property-value__agent"]'))
            writer.writerow([title, price, sold])
```

Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should understand what [strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm) are in python

In your examples that you have tried

```
RAW_URL = 13 Michael Way Cottees NSW 2017 + " "
RAW_URL = str(13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607)
RAW_DATA = ' " ' + (13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607) + ' " '
```

Here the characters you try to use a string are interpreted as actual code. To make your intentions clear to the interpreter use single quotes `'` around them. (or double quotes)

```
RAW_URL  = '13 Micheal Way Cottees NSW 2017'
RAW_DATA = '13 HOADLEY SY MAWSON ACT 2607'
```

To apply quotes use either string concatanation

```
RAW_URL = '"' + '13 Micheal Way Cottees NSW 2017' + '"'
```

Tough im not sure what you mean with raw paste data. Where is the data copied from? Is it by hand or done in the program?

Comment: i get a excel file daily that is street addresses. They are all exactly the same

13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607 >>> 


14 SAVERY ST GARRAN ACT 2605 >>>


202 41 CHANDLER ST BELCONNEN ACT 2617

Comment: Are you still copying the data by hand? (like copy + paste with your mouse). You could improve the code to read the excel file line by line and perform the web scraping that way.

Comment: the data is copied by hand as the excel sheet the data comes from is a web-based extract and is not recognised in python.

Comment: So, currently, what I have to do is take the raw text that is received in the download and then complete the following steps (bare in mind that each of these steps is done inside an excel template) **step 1** convert all letters to lower case > **step 2** remove all white spaces and replace with hyphen ( - ) > **step 3** concatenate body url (www.example.com/) **&** raw text into one cell > **step 4** add characters within bracket to start & end of string ( " ) > **step 5** copy and paste all lines into python list and run program >

Comment: I have figured out how to do steps 1,2,3 in python, but adding the (") characters to the text is just not seeming to work